# Storage Buffer Transfer to Graphics Synchronization

Tags: vulkan

I have a set of storage buffers I use to render my scene.These storage contains data related to meshes (vertices,indices etc...) and are used in indirect drawing. These buffers are created and then copied from an staging buffer using VkcmdCopyBuffer. So far I have put a `vkQueueWaitIdle(exclusive_transfer_queue)` right after submiting the copy command to avoid issues with synchronization. However, now I would like to remove the need for queuewaitIdle and have the ability to recreate all the storage buffers when needed Eg : When a new mesh is added to the scene. So  this is my attempt to synchronize the process of recreating the buffers (Transfers OP) and rendering.
The copy buffers functions uses this :

```
vkWaitForFences(device->getLogicalDevice(), 1, &async_loader.fence, VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);
    vkResetFences(device->getLogicalDevice(), 1, &async_loader.fence);
   
    VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo = {};
    beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
    beginInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT;
    vkBeginCommandBuffer(command_buffer, &beginInfo);

    VkBufferCopy copyRegion = {};
    copyRegion.size = device_size;

    vkCmdCopyBuffer(command_buffer,
                    src->getBufferHandle(),
                    dst->getBufferHandle(),
                    1,
                    &copyRegion);
    vkEndCommandBuffer(command_buffer);

    VkSubmitInfo submit_info = {};
    submit_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
    submit_info.commandBufferCount = 1;
    submit_info.pCommandBuffers = &command_buffer;
    submit_info.pSignalSemaphores = &async_loader.semaphore;
    submit_info.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
    vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, &submit_info, async_loader.fence);
    OnTransferCommand.invoke(async_loader.semaphore);
```

The setup consists of a single semaphore and a single fence. Whenever I create a storage buffer I use the fence to wait for the previous transfer submit to finishes. `OnTransferCommand.invoke(async_loader.semaphore);` Enqueues a new wait semaphore for the rendering vkqueuesubmit and the waitstage.  The rendering

```
     FrameData &frame_data = frames[current_frame];
    vkWaitForFences(device.getLogicalDevice(), 1, &frame_data.imageAvaibleFence, VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);
...

      VkResult result = vkAcquireNextImageKHR(device.getLogicalDevice(), swapChain.get_swap_chain_handle(), UINT64_MAX, frame_data.imageAcquiredSemaphore,
                                                VK_NULL_HANDLE,
                                                &next_image_index);
vkResetFences(device.getLogicalDevice(), 1, &frame_data.imageAvaibleFence);
record_command_index(frame_data.commandBuffer, next_image_index);

...

  submit_info.waitSemaphoreCount = uint32_t(queued_semaphores.size());
    submit_info.pWaitSemaphores    = queued_semaphores.data();
    submit_info.pWaitDstStageMask  = wait_stages.data();
...
VkPresentInfoKHR present_info      = {};
    present_info.sType                 = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;
    present_info.waitSemaphoreCount    = 1;
    present_info.pWaitSemaphores       = &frame_data.renderFinishedSemaphore;
vkQueuePresentKHR(device.getGraphicsQueueHandle(), &present_info)
```

The queue used in transferOP is different from graphics.
My issues is that my attempt is clearly a failure. Validaiton Layer that my graphics queue is waiting on a semaphore that can never be signaled. I assume this is a very common operation in any engine , so I would like to ask for help to spot what is wrong with my setup or any of the statements I've made in my first try or suggest ideas to achieve what I want to.
Thanks